# Typescript/Apollo Graphql - Invalid typing for apolloServer.executeOperation()

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, apollo-server

I'm trying to test a simple subgraph with `apolloServer.executeOperation`, but Typescript seems to have a problem with the return type of my data.

This is my test code

```js
  it('should fetch a user', async () => {
    const query = gql`
      query Query {
        user {
          id
          email
        }
      }
    `
    const response = await apolloServer.executeOperation<User>({
      query,
    })
    const util = require('util')
    console.log('response.body', util.inspect(response.body, { depth: null }))
    expect(response.body.kind).toEqual('single')
    expect(response.body.singleResult.data.user).toEqual({
      id: '1',
      email: 'fake@fakefunction.nl',
    })
  })
```

console.log output:

```
response.body {
  kind: 'single',
  singleResult: {
    data: [Object: null prototype] {
      user: [Object: null prototype] {
        id: '1',
        email: 'fake@fakefunction.nl'
      }
    },
    errors: undefined
  }
}
```

The tests are ok, but Typescript is complaining about the types of the response body:

```
Property 'singleResult' does not exist on type '{ kind: "incremental"; initialResult: GraphQLExperimentalFormattedInitialIncrementalExecutionResult<ObjMap<unknown>, ObjMap<unknown>>; subsequentResults: AsyncIterable<...>; } | { ...; }'.
  Property 'singleResult' does not exist on type '{ kind: "incremental"; initialResult: GraphQLExperimentalFormattedInitialIncrementalExecutionResult<ObjMap<unknown>, ObjMap<unknown>>; subsequentResults: AsyncIterable<...>; }'
```

The result of the query seems to typed as a `GraphQLResponse`, relevant typings here:

```
export type GraphQLResponseBody<TData = Record<string, unknown>> =
  | {
      kind: 'single';
      singleResult: FormattedExecutionResult<TData>;
    }
  | {
      kind: 'incremental';
      initialResult: GraphQLExperimentalFormattedInitialIncrementalExecutionResult;
      subsequentResults: AsyncIterable<GraphQLExperimentalFormattedSubsequentIncrementalExecutionResult>;
    };

export type GraphQLInProgressResponse<TData = Record<string, unknown>> = {
  http: HTTPGraphQLHead;
  body?: GraphQLResponseBody<TData>;
};

export type GraphQLResponse<TData = Record<string, unknown>> = WithRequired<
  GraphQLInProgressResponse<TData>,
  'body'
>;
```

So, IMHO, I get the type for the `incremental` type, but that should have been the 'single' kind right? Or am I missing something?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I guess temporary solution is cast it to the single result type until find a permanent solution ?

Answer (score 0):

This had me stumped for a while too.
I'm not sure what the shape of your `User` type is, but I've done something similar with an `Account`.

I believe the solution is in defining a response type with a key of (in your case) `ùser` typed to the `Ùser` result, then narrowing this type based on `kind === 'single'` or `kind === 'incremental'`.

Types can't be specified for incremental responses yet [(see this PR, which added types to single responses)](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/pull/6960).

This is how I got types working for a single response through typing my `<TData>` correctly and narrowing in a test.

```
it('returns the test accounts', async () => {

  interface Account {
    id: string
    firstname: string
    lastname: string
    email: string
  };

  type ResponseData = {
    accounts: Account[]
  }

  const response = await server.executeOperation<ResponseData>({ query }, {contextValue: context});

  // typescript needs the type narrowing in the `if()`to correctly type the resposeData object
  // response.body.singleResult.data has a type of undefined | null | ResponseData, so further narrowing is needed

  if(response.body.kind === 'single' && response.body.singleResult.data ) {
      let responseData: ResponseData = response.body.singleResult.data;
    expect(responseData.accounts[0].firstname).toEqual('firstname') // or whatever assertion is appropriate
   }

}
```

There could be a better way. However, in the context of testing where we should know what the data is going to be, I feel it's acceptable.

Edit:
Since we're mocking the response and know what is going to come back, we can create a response type and cast the response to it.

```
// in types.ts
export type SingleGraphQLResponse<ResponseData> = {
    body: {
        kind: 'single',
        singleResult: {
            data: ResponseData
        }
    }
}

// then in the test file...
 type ResponseData = {
      updateAccount: Account;
    };

    const response = await server.executeOperation<ResponseData>(
      { query: mutation, variables },
      { contextValue: context }
    ) as SingleGraphQLResponse<ResponseData>;

expect(response.body.singleResult.data).toMatchSnapshot() //or whatever assertion you want
```

This way, you could create the incremental response type and cast the response to it.